# reg expression with specific numbers and allow multiple

Tags: regex

I already have a reg expression that allows specific range of number (start with certain number) and length. Looking like this:

```
^((?!(0|2|4|5|6|7))[0-9]{6,7})$
```

How can I modify this expression, that I can add multiple numbers, separated by comma?

Comment: Try something like `^(?!.*(?:[024567]|1234|389))[0-9]+$` if you want to match a digit only string having no specific substrings in it.

Comment: If you just want to repeat a comma and 1+ digits after your first number try `^(?!([024-7]))[0-9]{6,7}(?:,[0-9]+)*$` Should the repeated numbers also have the same constraint?

Comment: If I understand well you want that your ReGex match numbers that doesn't start with 0|2|4|5|6|7  followed for any number and the length of the number to match have to be 6 or 7. If you wish that maybe that is the regular expression you are looking for:  https://regex101.com/r/dq0bkH/1/

Comment: @Thefourthbird, yes the repeated numbers should also have the same constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a repeating pattern that asserts what comes after the comma does not start with a digit in from the character class:

```
^(?!([024-7]))[0-9]{6,7}(?:,(?!([024-7]))[0-9]{6,7})*$
```

The added part matches:

- `(?:` Non capturing group
- `,(?!([024-7]))[0-9]{6,7}` Match comma and assert what is directly to the right is not a digit from the character class
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I37aLV/1)